# Create textview scrolling follow media player android

Tags: android, textview

I want create a textview vertical with multi line and it can auto scroll from top to down follow time play media player mp3.
How I can do it? here is my screen i need create
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKSB7.png)

Thank every one!